# Azure Unexpected TCP issue

Tags: connection, azure-sql-database, tcp

I've got an application that's been working for 9 months with no issue, but as of this morning (with no programming changes on my part), I'm timing out with SQL Server Error 10060.

In checking the server via SQL Studio there is some latency, and I've also had the same message, but less frequently.

In looking at the portal.azure page I'm assured that everything is OK.

What should one do when this happens?  My ISP looks fine; I've got the same speed as usual.

Comment: Does the error happen all the time or episodically? You may want to open a support ticket.

Comment: As of this morning, it's back to normal.  Though I did try a rash of things yesterday, nothing helped.  And as of this morning, it's all back to working fine.  I'm not sure where one raises a "free" support ticket, but for 29 USD/month (in addition to my current plan), I can ask whether there's a problem...